# WebGL not working for same spec system in chrome. How to fix?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

Using info from chrome://gpu and chrome://version

Both on Chrome version: 35.0.1916.153 (Official Build 274914) m
Both using an Nvidia 670 GTX

My driver: 9.18.13.3523

His driver: 9.18.13.4043

My webGL works perfectly, and my driver is slightly behind his. His webGL doesn't work even though in the settings it says all hardware accelerated, webGL enabled etc.

When he goes on page with webGL things they don't work - he can't see them just like you wouldn't see them with old browsers.

Why is this happening? How to diagnose/fix?

Comment: Same OS? What does chrome://gpu say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely Google has blacklisted the graphics driver because of the bugs.

You need to find out how start Chrome so that it ignores GPU blacklist. On some system it is this command line:

```
  google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

... and if it still doesn't work, the relevant console output etc. is needed.

More about blacklist:

http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists

Comment: Pretty late but I couldn't find anything to do with his driver in the blacklists and the chromium code I couldn't find anything to do with blacklisting it... I think it blacklisted because his driver has "beta" in its name although im still not sure how browsers are picking up on it (cant see anything in the chromium files). edit: and enabling it in chrome://flags fixed it thanks