# webGL is not working in Chromium, but it is in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, chromium

I have installed Chromium Version 31.0.1650.63 on CentOS release 6.5.

I also have firefox 24.6.0 installed

when I visit a web page in chromium that needs webGL, it says

```
Uncaught RuntimeError: The browser supports WebGL, but initialization failed.
```

I have checked the about:flags page the 'disable WebGL' attribute is NOT enabled

I visted

```
http://get.webgl.org/
```

Which said: Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card.

Visiting that same sight in firefox gave me the nice spinning cube 'success' page.

I visited

```
chrome://gpu/
```

and it said

```
WebGL: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL multisampling: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
```

Which I find hard to square with the same video card providing webgl support in firefox just fine.

Is this truly a video card driver issue or should I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is because Firefox and Chrome use different GPU blacklists.

Please try debugging tips provided here:

[WebGL not working for same spec system in chrome. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637534/webgl-not-working-for-same-spec-system-in-chrome-how-to-fix/24640596#24640596)

Comment: Agree with that, mostly CentOS is the problem (I've seen so many time happening with any linux distro) I would simply suggest to try enabling on chrome://flags "Override software rendering list"

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Intel integrated graphics chip, you might have to enable hardware acceleration (i.e. exposing the GPU functionality directly to certain software) for the X.org server of the X11 window system.

To do this edit or create the configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and put the following in there:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true" 
   Option      "DRI"    "3" 
EndSection
```

### Sources

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Configuration
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1595276#p1595276

Comment: DRI 3 did the trick for me. If I started google-chrome-beta from the console I got an error related to vulkan/dri 3

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue [after switching from the proprietary Nvidia to the nouveau drivers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660493#c8), a change which does not seem to have been picked up in the chromium GPU config of my profile. The fix is running `chromium-browser --single-process` *once* to reset the GPU configuration.